# REST API - авторизация/регистрация через соцсети и по email/password

Tags: php, rest, mobile-development, social-network

Требуется сделать регистрацию+авторизацию в мобильном приложении через соцсети или через емейл на удалённом REST API сервере (я отвечаю именно за сервер).

Сходу возник вопрос. При регистрации юзера через емейл/пароль, как отличить запрос приложения от запроса какого нибудь ботнета? Если просто принимать на веру что `/user/create?email=vasya@a.com&password=pupkin` делает только приложение, то можно в один прекрасный день обнаружить тонны "левых" юзеров в базе. Как вариант, можно слать письмо с подтверждающим линком, но может есть другие способы сразу отсеять "левые" запросы?

Другая трудность, регистрация и авторизация на rest api сервере в мобильных приложениях через социальные сети. Что должно прийти от мобильного приложения на сервер и как проверить эту информацию?

Не смог найти внятной информации на эту тему.  Подскажите какие-то best practices по реализации, желательно на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то по первой части вопроса, вот: https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc

По второй части:

- Laravel - https://appdividend.com/2017/07/12/laravel-facebook-login/
- Symfony - https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

Или гуглёж "social authentication php".